# E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 53 in source list

Tags: command-line, updates, software-center, sudo

I have done some looking around for a solution. However, I have come to the conclusion that the solution to my problem is just not on the internet. I am unable to update Ubuntu and download apps from the Software Center due to an error on line 53. Here is what is on line 53.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key
```

Is this line scripted correctly? If not, what should be on this line?

Answer (score 1):

No, this line is not a valid line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Just remove it.